# ¿Cómo puedo leer los datos de un archivo y pasarlos a un array en VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Buenas a todos y todas.

Necesito ayuda para hacer un trabajo con unos archivos. Dispongo de un archivo, que es una plantilla que se debe cargar automáticamente gracias a un archivo que elige el usuario. Este archivo que se rellena, será una plantilla que subirá los datos a SAP.

El archivo que carga el usuario, será xls o csv.

Estoy intentando crear una macro que me haga lo siguiente:

Cargar el archivo, eligiendo el usuario el que quiera,

Guardar esos datos en un Array bidimensional, para luego usarlos en la hoja de estilos actual (platilla que el usuario tendrá abierta cuando pulse en la macro).

Escribir los datos en ese archivo.

Lo que tengo hecho es:

```
Sub RellenarDoc()

 '
 ' RellenarDoc Macro
 ' Rellenar el documento para subir los datos a SAP
 '
 Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
 Dim FSO As Object, MyFile As Object
 Dim FileName As String, Arr As Variant


'only allow the user to select one file
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'determine what choice the user made
If intChoice <> 0 Then
    'get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
End If


End Sub
```

Es una parte de código que he encontrado por intenret. Lo siguiente que debería hacer, como digo, es guardar esos datos en un array y luego por ejemplo, obtener el array['A']['2'] (que es un identificador) para ponerlo en el archivo plantilla, hoja 1, posición A2

¿Puede alguien ayudarme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es que depende de qué tipo de archivo seleccione el usuario (xls o csv) procesaremos el fichero de una forma u otra.

Si es un excel puedes abrir el fichero, definir el rango de datos y cargar ese rango directamente a un array para luego utilizarlo donde quieras.

Con un csv el proceso es distinto:

```
Dim rawArray() As String
Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim ficherocsv As String

ficherocsv = "Rutafichero"

rawArray = Split(fichero.csv, ";")
ReDim varArray(LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray))

Dim index As Long
For index = LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray)
    varArray(index) = rawArray(index)
Next index
```

Luego, una vez cargado de un modo u otro cada fichero tendrías que tratarlos y llevar esos datos a excel definitivo.